# Javascript Object.defineProperties to Update Properties Automatically

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I am trying to make it to whenever I manually update rotationSetting.....such as rotation.rotationSetting = 7, the speed.steps# will be updated automatically by the object.

Right now, I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperties called on non-object" because rotationSetting is not a object. How do I get around this and accomplish what I want?

```
var rotation = function() {
    var rotationId;
    var rotationList = [];
    var rotationSetting = 3; 

    var speed = {  
        step1 : 0, 
        step2 : 0, 
        step3 : 0, 
        step4 : 0, 
    }  

    Object.defineProperties(rotationSetting, {
        set: function(rotationSetting, speed) {
            this.step1 = rotationSetting * 1000;
            this.step2 = this.step1 + 1000;
            this.step3 = this.step2 + this.step1;
            this.step4 = this.step3 + 1000;
        }  
    }) 
    return {
        rotationId : rotationId,
        rotationList : rotationList,
        rotationSetting : rotationSetting,
        speed : speed,
    }  
}();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pay more attention to how `Object.defineProperty` is used. The first parameter is the object you define the property on, the second is the property name.

```
var rotation = function() {
    var rotationId;
    var rotationList = [];

    var speed = {  
        step1 : 0, 
        step2 : 0, 
        step3 : 0, 
        step4 : 0
    } ;

    var result = {
        rotationId : rotationId,
        rotationList : rotationList,
        speed : speed
    }  
    Object.defineProperty(result, 'rotationSetting',{
        set: function(val) {
            speed.step1 = val * 1000;
            speed.step2 = speed.step1 + 1000;
            speed.step3 = speed.step2 + speed.step1;
            speed.step4 = speed.step3 + 1000;
        }  
    });
    return result;
}();

console.log(rotation.speed.step1);
rotation.rotationSetting = 7;
console.log(rotation.speed.step1);
```

EDIT: Updated the example to fit your usage better.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/AZUKAfO/1/edit Could you edit the code or provide your own sample that shows step1 to be 0?

Comment: I see, I was doing rotation.speed.step1 instead of rotation.step1. How come rotation.speed.step1 doesn't return the new value since this.step1 updates rotation.speed.step1?

Comment: If you want rotationSetting to update speed.step, instead of `this.step1 = rotationSetting * 1000` do `speed.step1 = rotationSetting * 1000`

Comment: With this.step1...is it causing 2 instances of speed= {} to exist in memory? Also, console.log(rotation.speecd.step1) shows 0 when I do   speed.step1 = rotationSetting * 1000 instead of this.step1

Comment: I updated the example so you can use rotation.speed.step1. You will now have a single instance of speed.

Answer (score 2):

The method signature is this one: `Object.defineProperties( object, propertyName, { /* definition */ });`

Don't save the values in variables, save them directly on the object you return.

Comment: he isn't returning `this` - he's returning a different object.

Answer (score 2):

`rotationSetting` isn't a property, it's a locally scoped variable.  You cannot therefore use `Object.defineProperty` on it.

Correct usage would be:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'rotationSetting', {
    set: ...
});
```

Where `obj` is the object that you're going to return to the caller.

Note that if you do this without removing `var rotationSetting` you will have *two* `rotationSetting` variables - the one you've already declared, and `this.rotationSetting`.